# Connecting to an MS SQL database and using Libreoffice as the frontend

Tags: libreoffice

I am looking to upgrade my company computers at work to Ubuntu from Windows XP, however we have a bespoke MS Access program that connects to our MS SQL server in the USA. Is there away to connect using FreeTDS and writing the bespoke program in Libreoffice Base. If so how would I connect this.  Detailed instructions would be nice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear if you are using windows or linux clients, so ...

There is a whole wiki page on how to configure just this here:

http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Connect_MySQL_and_Base

It describes configuration for windows and linux clients, including Ubuntu.

Edit for a MS SQL database see

http://www.finefrog.com/2008/04/14/connecting-to-an-mssql-server-and-others-with-openofficeorg/

It appears to be working from the comments, but I do not have a MS SQL server to confirm.

Comment: he ask for MS(microsoft) SQL not MY

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go. Btw I have Ubuntu with liber office and want to connect to an mssql server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice this helped.  Although JTDS is very slow to collect data from MSSQL

Comment: The link about MS SQL is down